# A expressão FYI pode ser utilizada num contexto formal?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, português-europeu, expressões-idiomáticas, expressões-equivalentes

A expressão FYI pode ser utilizada num contexto Formal?

Costumo receber email reencaminhados apenas com esta expressão.

Comment: Eu não reconheço FYI como uma abreviatura válida da língua portuguesa.  Nós temos as três palavras em nossa língua.  Porque então não escrever "para sua informação" ou então "psi"/"pvi"?

Comment: @Centaurus na minha área é usual acontecer isso. Mas eu também acho que podíamos usar a versão portuguesa por extenso. Também não me diz nada PSI ou PVI. Parece sigla de imposto. eheheh

Comment: Com algumas pesquisas, verifiquei que trata-se de For Your Information , nao formal

Comment: In Brazilian companies nowadays it is very common to forward emails with just "PSC" (Para Seu Conhecimento) written on it. I have been usually sending and receiving this not only from co-workers but also clients and suppliers. Seems to be very diffused here for a long time. For instance, I found one of the biggest newspapers in Brazil recommending it at least since 2007 (https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/publifolha/316916-veja-como-evitar-gafes-e-mal-entendidos-nas-mensagens-eletronicas.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, num contexto formal típico, a abreviação *FYI* não poderia ser usada.

Uma possível exceção poderia ser em, digamos, uma companhia de tecnologia de informação em que fosse de praxe misturar expressões do inglês com português. Mas, mesmo nesse caso, seria provavelmente mais preciso dizer que as comunicações na empresa são em linguagem informal, e não que "FYI" é aceitável num contexto formal.

Até porque, mesmo em inglês, a abreviação dificilmente seria adequada num contexto formal, como se pode ver, e.g., nessa [resposta](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/209237) do English SE, que inclui:

> I would certainly not use FYI in certain formal writing situations.
>    <sub>(Eu certamente não usaria FYI em certas situações de escrita formal.)</sub>

E é importante frisar que *FYI* não pode ser considerado parte da língua portuguesa. Como Timbane argumenta em seu artigo ["A Formação De Palavras A Partir De Siglas E Acrônimos Estrangeiros Na Língua Portuguesa"](https://revistas.pucsp.br/verbum/article/view/18307), VERBUM, n.6, p.50 (2014):

> Entendemos que não basta a dicionarização para definir a desneologização de uma sigla/acrônimo. É preciso haver o que o linguista francês Jean François Sablayrolles designa por “sentimento neológico”. Quem determina a permanência de uma sigla/acrônimo proveniente de uma língua estrangeira é a frequência do uso.

O uso de *FYI* não me parece difundido o bastante. E, apontado que a dicionarização não basta para se considerar a palavra como parte do português, vale mencionar que *FYI* sequer é listado em qualquer dos dicionários de português que chequei (Koogan Larousse, Priberam, Infopédia, Michaelis, Aulete e Dicio) com exceção do [Dicionário Informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/fyi/).

Comment: Good answer and sensible advice.